# Java: Modifying arguments of an anonymous function which is passed as a callable

Tags: java

I am creating a generic iterator which is passed a String object and a callable in Java. The callable argument needs to be changed with respect to the iterations. For example, for initial 5 iterations the argument is `X` and for next 5 iterations the argument should be `Y`.

I already have separate callable methods. I was trying to pass those methods through lambda expression in place of callable, but I found that the Callable interface doesn't allow modification of arguments from with in the iterator. Can someone suggest about the possible actions possible with Java?

Another option, I have in hand is to create out a Callable object and pass it to the iterator. I believe that'll do the purpose, but I was more interested in passing it as anonymised functions.

Example: I have an iterator similar to

```
public class CustomIterator<Type> implements Iterable<Type> {

    private int offset;
    private int maxOffset = 1000;
    private Callable<Object> function;

    public CustomIterator(Callable<Object> function) {
        this.offset = 0;
        this.function = function;
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Type>() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return (offset < maxOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public Type next() {
                //* Some Logic here 

                try {

                    // Pass offset to the Callable function
                    Type t = (Type) function.call();
                // increment offset based on the value of t
                    return t;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

By the way, I am using Java 11, so if there is a specific feature related to that version that'll work as well.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you're actually trying to do - can you elaborate, ideally with some piece of code (what it might look like if it would work the way you want it to)?

Comment: Can you add sample code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Are you trying to write a morphic function? You need to express your intention more clearly for people to help you. Also the code snippet would be useful. My guess is that you want to modify the argument of a call from within the call. That usually does not work. I suppose you need a 'carry' object to modify iteratively.

Comment: I have added the code snippet. I am trying to modify the arguments of the function call from with in the iterator. Since the callable is passed as a lambda expression from the top, the arguments are pre-decided and currently I can't find a way to modify them at the time it is being called out.